# How to show this series is divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{n} +1}{n-1}$$

This series diverges (according to wolfram alpha), but how exactly can I show this is true? I am guessing you can do this with the comparison test, but I don't exactly know what to compare to.

Comment: Try [LCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.  Comparison test is harder to use and less helpful than LCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compare with $$\frac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n}$$
see, the two terms are diverge

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n-1} = \dfrac1{\sqrt{n}-1}$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=2}^M\dfrac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n-1} = \sum_{n=2}^M\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}-1} > \sum_{n=2}^M \dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}$$
Hence, it diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following test by a suitable $p$:

> Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}~n^pu_n=A$. Then:
>
> - If $p>1$ and $A$ is finite then $\sum u_n$ converges.
> - If $p\le1$ and $A\neq0$ or $A=\infty$ then $\sum u_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The series diverges.
Indeed: $$\dfrac{\sqrt{n} +1}{n-1}\sim_{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\sim_{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
that diverges.